# Angular: Why would package-lock.json have higher versions of packages than package.json after fresh npm install?

Tags: angular, npm

My understanding is that npm (back in 2017?) made the decision to update any packages with higher versions in package.json than in package-lock.json on package-lock.json.

I am observing this interesting phenomenon of my project seemingly spontaneously upgrading packages that I don't want it to upgrade.

For instance, I've recently switched to Angular 9, and I've started to experience weird errors like :

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

I have [tried to reproduce this on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-1dz9hr) with no luck (i.e., I don't get that same error on stack blitz: it seems to work fine there). Because [stack blitz does something weird with core-js](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/930), I decided to downgrade my version of core-js on my local project (github version [here](https://github.com/Atticus29/dataJitsu/tree/tableFilterFromStackBlitzGenericV2SO)) to match as closely as possible what was working on stack blitz.

Here's where I am confused. I deleted node_modules *and* package-lock.json, and changed my package.json to the following:

```
{
  "name": "data-jitsu",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "cypress open"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.9",
    "@types/youtube": "^0.0.29",
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.2-1",
    "core-js": "^2.0.0",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "firebase": "^7.15.0",
    "grpc": "^1.24.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng-starrating": "^1.0.7",
    "ngx-materialize": "^6.1.3",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "^7.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "stripe": "^7.9.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
    "@types/d3": "^4.13.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "10.0.4",
    "chance": "^1.1.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cypress": "^3.8.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.36.1"
  }
}
```

Upon running `npm install`, package-lock.json is restored, and looks like [this](https://github.com/Atticus29/dataJitsu/blob/tableFilterFromStackBlitzGenericV2SO/package-lock.json) (too long for this SO question).

It seems like there are many different versions of core-js in package-lock.json, some of which are above v3.0.0, even though I specified `"core-js": "^2.0.0"` in package.json. Could someone explain why, and why this behavior, if not a bug, is desireable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have specified the corejs version as 2.0.0, some of your dependencies might require the higher version to satisfy their requirements. For example, your @angular-devkit/build-angular requires the corejs version(3.1.4) which is significantly higher than the package you have mentioned. This might cause having multiple versions of corejs exists in the same. Core idea is that npm resolves dependencies in the order they have been mentioned in the package.json. Below link will give you an idea how the dependencies are getting resolved

https://medium.com/@imdongchen/how-does-npm-handle-conflicting-package-versions-44f90950cca5